# how to group data entries with same id into a single entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, typescript, typeorm

I am a beginner in MySQL as well as Typeorm. So my query returns data with the same ID like:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "john",
    place: "San Francisco"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "john",
    place: "Mumbai"
  }
]
```

Now I want data where there is an entry with a unique id, let's say:

```
[
 {
  id: "1",
  name: "john",
  place: ["San Francisco", "Mumbai"]
  }
]
```

can someone help me, how do I groupBy to achieve this result?

Comment: What sql query are you running? I guess you should join records to get the expected outcome

Comment: @microcosme not join but aggregate (JSON_ARRAYAGG function).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can get an array, but you could use group_concat.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/
The query would be something like

```
SELECT `id`, group_concat(`name`), group_concat(`place`) FROM <table_name> GROUP BY `id`
```

*if the name doesn't need to be concatenated*

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, group_concat(`place`) FROM <table_name> GROUP BY `id`
```

And then in your code you can split that string in array. Either use ',' which I think it's the default separator or use a custom one like '!#$!'

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT 
  id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(place) 
FROM 
  <table_name> 
GROUP BY 
  id
```

With TypeScript you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [{id: "1",name: "john",place: "San Francisco"},{id: "1",name: "john",place: "Mumbai"}]

const dataHash = data.reduce((a, { id, name, place }) => {
  a[id] = a[id] || { id, name, place: [] } 
  a[id].place.push(place)
  return a
}, {})
const result = Object.values(dataHash)

console.log(result)
```